# Residual minimizing matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, projection

I'm trying to solve a linear system of equations $$Ax = b,$$$A\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}, x,b\in\mathbb R^n$. The linear system is an iteration in a nonlinear solution procedure. The nonlinear system is very sensitive to the initial guess.

I can solve it on a very small problem, let's call this the solution to the problem $A_1u_1 = b_1,\ u_1\in \mathbb R^m, \ m<n$. I want to use a projection of $u_1$ as an initial guess for the underlying original system. I introduce the matrix $P\ \in\mathbb R^{n\times m}$ such that it minimizes the residual
$$ ||APu_1-b||_2.$$
I was wondering if there exists a known procedure in order to find $P$? I have tried to do some kind of adapted minimal residual method, but know minimizing in $P$ in stead of $u$, but this lead nowhere.

Any help is appreciated, a reference to useful literature as much as a real solution to my problem,

Comment: What is 'a linear system is an iteration in a nonlinear solution procedure. "?

Comment: Say the coefficients of $\tilde A$ and $\tilde b$ are dependent on $x$, then these can be approximated (e.g. take $x$ from the previous iteration, making them constant) resulting in approximations $A\approx \tilde A$ and $b\approx \tilde b$, resulting in the linear system. Furthermore, it is not necessary to know the underlying nonlinear solver to answer this question.

Comment: So it's similar to Newton's method?

Comment: Yeah it's a fixed point method

Comment: square the expression, take the derivative, set to 0 and you have a linear system you can solve for $P$